# Postgresql if null in field,the whole sql is null

Tags: postgresql

I use this sql to execute sql:

```
    v_sql4 :='
    INSERT INTO public.rebatesys(head,contract_no,history_no,f_sin,line_no,s_line_no,departmentcd,catagorycd,jan,seriescd,f_exclude,     f_del,ins_date,ins_time,ins_user_id,ins_func_id,ins_ope_id,upd_date,upd_time,upd_user_id,upd_func_id,upd_ope_id)                                   
     VALUES (0, '''||v_contract_no||''', '||v_history_no||',1, '||v_line_no||', '||v_down_s_line_no||', '||coalesce(v_deptCD,null)||', '||0||', '''||v_singleJan||''','''||0||''','||v_fExclude||',
    0, current_date, current_time, '||v_ins_user_id||', 0, 0,
    current_date,current_time,'||v_upd_user_id||',0, 0);';
RAISE NOTICE 'v_sql4 IS : %', v_sql4;
    EXECUTE v_sql4;
```

But when field "v_deptCD" is null,the whole sql is null,even I use `coalesce`,I still can't do id, the out put is :

```
NOTICE:  v_sql4 IS : <NULL>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `v_deptCD` is null, you want to replace it by the **string** `'null'`, not the **keyword**.

```
', '||coalesce(v_deptCD,'null')||', '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
case when v_deptCD notnull then v_deptCD else null end
```

or use this for string concatination inside sql

```
concat(field1, ', ', field2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach to JGH solution is to use function [format(your_string, list, of, values)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.9.7.2.2.11.1.1), it can ignore NULL values, but has the option to display them as `NULL` if you use `%L` in your format string. It will however single quote numbers if you use that format specifier, requiring casting in some cases.

> Format arguments according to a format string. This function is similar to the C function sprintf. See [Section 9.4.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).

But in my opinion best solution is to use `USING` clause and pass values in there. It looks kinda like prepared statement, protects you from SQL Injection, but does not cache plans like prepared statements. There are simple examples on how to do this in documentation for [executing dynamic commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE inserted_by = $1 AND inserted <= $2'
   INTO c
   USING checked_user, checked_date;
```